# Guide for MIDI?

Tags: midi

*Where can I get the Roland D-20 guide book for MIDI?
I looked at RolandUs.com but they didn't have it there.*

Comment: There are plenty of books on MIDI. Can you elaborate on what particular aspects of MIDI you are interested in? What do you want to use MIDI for?

Comment: I've been reading the manual to my Roland D-20. I got to the second volume of it and it said to read the "MIDI Guide book" before proceeding.

Comment: @Mark Heath any help?

Comment: It sounds like it is referring to a specific book, so it is hard to know what that book covers.

Comment: It is referring to a specific book but I bought it used and didn't come with that book. Do you know where I can download that book?

Comment: As asked, the question is really vague.  It sounds like you want a general guide to MIDI, but the in the comments, it sounds like you are looking for a specific book for your synthesizer.  Could you edit your question to clarify?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a read of this short [Introduction to MIDI](http://www.midi.org/aboutmidi/intromidi.pdf) PDF from Roland. This will give you an overview of what MIDI is and what it can be used for. Then you might be in a better position to tell us what topics you are interested in exploring further.

Comment: +1 That has to be the most detailed and relevant introduction to MIDI I have ever seen.

Answer (score 3):

The manual actually says:

> When using the D-20 in Multi Timbral mode, please read the ***supplied*** "MIDI Guide book" before this owners manual.

Apparently the keyboard originally came with the MIDI Guide book.  I was unable to find it online.

From what I have seen in the D-50 owners manuals about MIDI and from what I can infer from the D-20 manual, I don't think it would be much help to you.

The document recommended by Mark Heath would be a great place to start.  On page 7 it describes that "Multitimbral" simply means that the device can play multiple sounds at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for trying to find it. I couldn't find one either.

Answer (score 3):

The original "[**MIDI Guide Book**](https://ia902502.us.archive.org/3/items/manuallib-id-2725326/2725326_text.pdf)" supplied with the D-20 and other new Roland synths/samplers can be downloaded from the archive.org website

[***https://ia902502.us.archive.org/3/items/manuallib-id-2725326/2725326_text.pdf***](https://ia902502.us.archive.org/3/items/manuallib-id-2725326/2725326_text.pdf)